# Using a constructor in a book class c# console application

Tags: c#

I have a class that holds a couple of books and prints them out in the console screen, here is my code:

```
class Book
{
    public string forfattareEfternamn;
    public string forfattareFornamn;
    public string bokensTittle;
    public int lanseringsDatum;

    public Book(string forfattareEfternamn, string forfattareFornamn, string bokensTittle, int lanseringsDatum)
    {


    }   


    public string BokensTittle
    {
        get { return bokensTittle; }
        set { bokensTittle = value; }
    }
    public string ForfattareFornamn
    {
        get {return forfattareFornamn;}
        set {forfattareFornamn = value;}
    }

    public string ForfattareEfternamn
    {
        get {return forfattareEfternamn;}
        set {forfattareEfternamn = value;;}
    }

    public int LanseringsDatum
    {
        get { return lanseringsDatum; }
        set { lanseringsDatum = value; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3} ", forfattareEfternamn, ForfattareFornamn, bokensTittle, lanseringsDatum);

    }
}
```

Main:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Book> books = new List<Book>(string forfatareFornamn, string forfattareEfternamn, string bokensTittle, int lanseringsDatum);
        books.Add(new Book { forfattareFornamn = "Dumas", forfattareEfternamn = "Alexandre", bokensTittle = "The Count Of Monte Cristo", lanseringsDatum = 1844 });
        books.Add(new Book { forfattareFornamn = "Clark", forfattareEfternamn = "Arthur C", bokensTittle = "Rendezvous with Rama", lanseringsDatum = 1972 });
        books.Add(new Book { forfattareFornamn = "Dumas", forfattareEfternamn = "Alexandre", bokensTittle = "The Three Musketeers", lanseringsDatum = 1844 });
        books.Add(new Book { forfattareFornamn = "Defoe", forfattareEfternamn = "Daniel", bokensTittle = "Robinson Cruise", lanseringsDatum = 1719 });
        books.Add(new Book { forfattareFornamn = "Clark", forfattareEfternamn = "Arthur C", bokensTittle = "2001: A space Odyssey", lanseringsDatum = 1968 });

        foreach (Book b in books)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(b);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is that I'm told to use a constructor that holds in the data types so I dodnt have to write down all the book names one by one, and Im actually not sure how I should make it. I tried:

```
public Book(string forfattareEfternamn, string forfattareFornamn, string bokensTittle, int lanseringsDatum)
    {


    }
```

but it gives me error saying I have no constructor that takes 0 arguments. Any ideas?

Comment: Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ace5hbzh.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If this is your constructor:

```
public Book(string forfattareEfternamn, string forfattareFornamn, string bokensTittle, int lanseringsDatum)
{
}
```

This line will not compile:

```
new Book { forfattareFornamn = "Dumas", forfattareEfternamn = "Alexandre", bokensTittle = "The Count Of Monte Cristo", lanseringsDatum = 1844 })
```

If you create a `parametrized constructor` then you no longer have a `default constructor`. Therefore you ran into this compiler error.

### You can do two things:

**1)** If you want this to compile add a parameter less constructor in your `Book` class.

```
public Book() {}
```

**2)** Or change the code in your main class so that it corresponds to your parametrized constructor `new Book("blah", "blah", etc);`

Answer (score 0):

`new Book { ... }` is implicitly `new Book() { ... }` - i.e. it uses the default constructor. If you add a custom constructor, then you might want to also add an explicit parameterless constructor:

```
public Book() {}
```

The issue here is that if you don't define *any* constructors (on a non-abstract class), it adds an implicit public parameterless constructor that calls down to `: base()` - however, if you add *any* custom constructor, it does **not** do this.

or alternatively - change the other code, i.e.

```
books.Add(new Book("Dumas", "Alexandre", "The Count Of Monte Cristo", 1844 ));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your `List` initialization is wrong:

```
List<Book> books = new List<Book>(string forfatareFornamn, string forfattareEfternamn, string bokensTittle, int lanseringsDatum);
```

change it to:

```
List<Book> books = new List<Book>();
```

then after calling constructor you do not assign values to fields, do it like this:

```
public Book(string forfattareEfternamn, string forfattareFornamn, string bokensTittle, int lanseringsDatum) 
{
   this.forfattareEfternamn = forfattareEfternamn;
   this.forfattareFornamn = forfattareFornamn;
   this.bokensTittle =bokensTittle;
   this.lanseringsDatum = lanseringsDatum;
}
```

And last error is your logic calling `Book` constructor:

```
(new Book { forfattareFornamn = "Dumas", forfattareEfternamn = "Alexandre", bokensTittle = "The Count Of Monte Cristo", lanseringsDatum = 1844 });
```

change it to this:

```
books.Add((new Book ("Dumas", "Alexandre", "The Count Of Monte Cristo", 1844));
```